# Linq Dynamic Expressions Groupby with sum

Tags: c#, linq

I cannot figure out how to do a `Linq.Dynamic` on an `ObservableCollection` and sum some fields.  Basically I want to do this;

```
var group
     from x in MyCollection
     group x by x.MyField into g
     select new MyClass
     {
         MyField = g.Key,
         Total = g.Sum(y => y.Total)
     };
```

Figured it would be this in Linq.Dynamic;

```
var dGroup = MyCollection
             .GroupBy("MyField ", "it")
             .Select("new (it.Key as MyField , it as new MyClass { Total  = sum(it.Total ) })");
```

However this keeps give me errors.

FYI `MyCollection` is a `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`

Edit:

I am sorry did not make this very clear.  The reason I need it to be `Linq.Dynamic` is that the actual `MyClass` has about 10 properties that user can pick to group the collection `MyCollection` in.  To make matters worse is the user can select multiple grouping.  So hand coding the groups isn't an option.  So while @Harald Coppoolse does work it requires that myClass.MyField to be hand coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this might not be the best way, but it is the only I found.  FYI it more manual work than standard LINQ.

Here is the new Dynamic Linq;

```
var dGroup = MyCollection
         .GroupBy("MyField ", "it")
         .Select("new (it.Key as MainID, it as MyClass)");
```

The next problem is not only do you need to iterate through each `MainID` but you need to iterate through `MyClass` and sum for each `MainID`;

```
foreach (dynamic r in dGroup)
{
        foreach (dynamic g in r.MyClass)
        {
               gTotal = gTotal + g.Total;
        }
 }
```

If someone can show me a better way to do this I will award the correct answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

So `MyCollection` is a sequence of `MyClass` objects, where every `MyClass` object has at least two properties: `MyField` and `Total`.

You want the sum of all `Total` values that have the same value for `MyField`

For example:

```
MyField  Total
   X       10
   Y        5
   X        7
   Y        3
```

You want a sequence with two elements: one for the X with a grand total of 10 + 7 = 17; and one for the Y with a grand total of 5 + 3 = 8

In method syntax:

```
var result = MyCollection.Cast<MyClass>()      // take all elements of MyCollection
    .GroupBy(myClass => myClass.MyField)       // Group into groups with same MyField
    .Select(group => new MyClass()             // for every group make one new MyClass object
    {
        MyField = group.Key,
        Total = group                          // to calculate the Total:
            .Select(groupElement => groupElement.Total) // get Total for all elements in the group
            .Sum(),                                     // and sum it
    })
```

If your `ObservableCollection` is in fact an `ObservableCollection<MyClass>` than you won't need the `Cast<MyClass>` part.

There is a lesser known [GroupBy overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) that will do this in one statement. I'm not sure if this one will improve readability:

```
var result = MyCollection.Cast<MyClass>()   // take all elements of MyCollection
    .GroupBy(myClass => myClass.MyField,    // group into groups with same MyField
        myClass => myClass.Total,           // for every element in the group take the Total
        (myField, totals) => new MyClass()  // from the common myField and all totals in the group
        {                                   // make one new MyClass object
            MyField = myField,              // the common myField of all elements in the group
            Total = totals.Sum(),           // sum all found totals in the group
        });
```